# how to check if an element is in the DOM with Fluid

Tags: html, typo3, fluid

I want to show a div only if another div is visible in the DOM. There is a way to do it with Fluid?

A kind of `if( $('.divA).length ) { $('.divB').show() }` for jQuery.

It should sounds like:

```
<f:if condition="<div class="divA">">
    <div class=divB"></div>
</f:if>
```

But it's of course wrong.

Comment: _“But it's of course wrong.”_ - so is trying to “do this with fluid” in the first place - it has no idea what you might have output elsewhere earlier on the page, and it for sure can’t look into the future to be able to “expect” elements you might output only later. If this decision was somehow based on your _data_, then it would make sense to do this in the template.

Comment: How are you deciding whether to display `divA`? Can you use that same decision to display `divB`?